# How i rebuilt PHP to new version

Tags: php, apache

Today, i download php-5.5.4-Win32-VC11-x86(Thread safe) and extract it particular folder and change the httpd.conf as follows

```
LoadModule php5_module "D:/Software/php-5.5.4-Win32-VC11-x86/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "D:/Software/php-5.5.4-Win32-VC11-x86"
```

My older version is **php-5.4.15-Win32-VC9-x86**

When i run the phpinfo() function it always show older version number and it not rebuilted.

See attached image

[image: PHP NOT REBUILD]

You see in image, the configuration file is in new version but the build date and compiler not changes...so the extension of new version not works

Anybody please give the instruction, how to rebuilt PHP with correct microsoft compiler and version

**Edit:**

I change windows environment PATH to new php folder as

PHP PATH

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin;D:\Software\php-5.5.4-Win32-VC11-x86;D:\Software\mysql-5.6.11-win32\bin;C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
```

as well i restart apache and system many times

Comment: Did you restart/reload apache?

Comment: yes, i restart apache many times....

Comment: Have you uninstalled the old version? Have you manually installed apache and PHP or are you using WAMP or similar tool? Have you disabled the php.conf that may be at the folder conf.d/php.conf?

Comment: I manually install apache and php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the *[documentation](http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.5)*:

> If you are using PHP with Apache 1 or Apache2 from apache.org (not
>   recommended) you need to use the older VC6 versions of PHP compiled
>   with the legacy Visual Studio 6 compiler. Do NOT use VC9+ versions of
>   PHP with the apache.org binaries.

According to the screen-shot it seems you're using Apache2.0 - try downloading the latest Apache version provided by [*Apache Lounge*](http://www.apachelounge.com/) and if that doesn't work re-install PHP 5.5.4

You can also try the following:

1. Make sure to change the path in http.conf to point to the new php.ini (variable name: `PHPIniDir`)
2. Change the `PATH` in the system variables (make sure to remove the old path!)
3. re-install  install [VC++ Redistribution](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)
4. restart your computer

Comment: I have latest VC11 Apache, and `phpinfo()` still says that it uses Apache 2.0 handler.

Comment: I use apache httpd-2.4.4-win32 download from apache lounge

Comment: Yes, of course (Apache 2.4.6 x86 VC11). And I quote `phpinfo()`: `Apache 2.0 Handler`, but latest build.

Comment: @TamilSelvan One more thing to check: the `PATH` variable - make sure it points to the new PHP folder

Comment: Yes, i change windows environment path also to new php folder

Comment: it shows as
`PHP 5.5.4 (cli) (built: Sep 18 2013 13:04:23) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies`

Comment: When you changed the `PATH` did you remove the path to the folder of the old version ? also, you can try to restart your computer.

Comment: Did you also change the path in http.conf to point to the new `php.ini` ? The variable is called `PHPIniDir`

Comment: yes, i change PHPIniDir as PHPIniDir "D:/Software/php-5.5.4-Win32-VC11-x86" "D:/Software/php-5.5.4-Win32-VC11-x86" in httpd.conf

Comment: @TamilSelvan according to the screen-shot `php.ini` was loaded from `c:\windows` so I believe it was loaded with the wrong `php.ini`. What doesn `phpinfo()` show now ?

Comment: I follow ur answer, It not change, phpinfo() shows same as attached image now also...i also flush dns

Comment: Try to install the following: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679 it's required for VC11

Comment: @alfasin Thanks a lot, i fixed by reinstall VC++ Redistribution 2012